# How to add a custom view to top of tableView in UIViewController and be able to scroll together

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm trying to put a big `UIImageView` on top of a `UITableView` inside my `UIViewController`. I read that I should not put a `UITableView` inside a UIScrollView and so I'm trying to find out how to best approach this.

Right now, in my `UIViewController` what I have is a huge `UIImageView` (covering half of screen) and below that I have my `UITableView`. 
The problem is that the scroll only works for the `UITableViewCell`, but I cannot scroll up so that the image goes to the top and invisible...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can use one tableview, and you can put the image view in the table view first cell!!!

Comment: @Mr.T got it. Very simple. The reason a scroll view isn't needed in a UITableView because the scrollView is a subclass of UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the tableview the height of the view controller's view then in viewDidLoad say something like:

```
self.imageView.removeFromSuperView()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.imageView
```

If you're using auto layout you should move the second line to viewsDidLayoutSubviews